# PHP Increase Upload File Size

Tags: php, file-upload, max

Is there a limit to the max uploaded size in php.ini ?

I want to change it Like so:

`upload_max_filesize = 4096 M` or `4 G`

```
post_max_size = 4 G
```

Comment: yes it is possible, change it in php.ini file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 4000M

 Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 4000M
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be needing to set the value of **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size variables** in your php.ini :

```
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
post_max_size = 5000M
```